# Updated Raspbian Wheezy and now some services don't start on boot

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues, update

A week or so ago I updated (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`) two Raspberry Pi 2s after a few weeks since the last time I had done so. As I normally do at this opportunity, I rebooted them.

I have a few services that (up until now) start on boot; BitTorrent Sync, OMSAgent and my own custom Upstart script for AutoSSH. Since that update - with some random chance that I can't detect - some of these services don't start on their own.

I don't seem to be able to see anything in `/var/log/syslog` nor `/var/log/messages` but I've only recently begun to get a grip of syslogging in Linux, so may be looking in the wrong place for service starts/failures.

The only thing that seems to be erroring is `ntpd`

```
Mar 29 22:10:01 hostname ntpdate[424]: step-systime: Invalid argument
Mar 29 22:10:01 hostname ifplugd(eth0)[287]: Program executed successfully.
Mar 29 22:10:50 hostname ntpdate[1295]: step time server 131.188.3.220 offset 39.486146 sec
Mar 29 22:10:54 hostname ntpd[1354]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Mon Nov  2 04:29:31 UTC 2015 (1)
Mar 29 22:10:54 hostname ntpd[1355]: proto: precision = 1.250 usec
Mar 29 22:10:54 hostname ntpd[1355]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Mar 29 22:10:54 hostname ntpd[1355]: Listen normally on 1 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Mar 29 22:10:54 hostname ntpd[1355]: Listen normally on 2 eth0 192.168.254.50 UDP 123
Mar 29 22:10:54 hostname ntpd[1355]: peers refreshed
Mar 29 22:10:54 hostname ntpd[1355]: Listening on routing socket on fd #19 for interface updates
Mar 29 22:10:54 hostname ntpd[1355]: restrict: error in address '::' on line 38. Ignoring...
Mar 29 22:10:54 hostname ntpd[1355]: restrict: error in address '::1' on line 42. Ignoring...
```

**Info**:

```
user@hostname ~ $ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
user@hostname ~ $ uname -a
Linux hostname 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT 2016-03-29 22:59 BST:**

Posting `ntp.conf`:

```
pi@lon-rpi-stash ~ $ cat /etc/ntp.conf
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift


# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


# You do need to talk to an NTP server or two (or three).
#server ntp.your-provider.example

# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst


# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient
```

**EDIT 2016-04-05 00:27 BST:**

Is there any chance that this behaviour is because I'm running Upstart on these RPis on Raspbian Wheezy? And I'm just seeing a quirk/bug in the behaviour? (it should be noted that only my custom AutoSSH wrapper is written using Upstart conf, the rest are standard init.d scripts)

Comment: Please post your `ntpd` config file as well.

Comment: @Will I've never modified it; so it should be default. Updating question now...